# Can I use ProgressCallback for loadInBackground? parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-progressbar

I have a ParseImageView in my ListView inheriting from parse.com database. But android studio says it cannot resolve the method ProgressCallback.
Code:

```
 @Override
public View getItemView(Campaign campaign, View v, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_single, null);
    }

    super.getItemView(campaign, v, parent);
    ParseImageView mealImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    ParseFile photoFile = campaign.getImage();
    if (photoFile != null) {
        mealImage.setParseFile(campaign.getImage());
        mealImage.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                           // nothing to do

                                       }
                                   }
                , new ProgressCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(Integer percentDone) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        progressBar.setProgress(percentDone);
                    }

                }

        )

    }
    if (photoFile == null) {
        mealImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_icon);

    }

    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
    titleTextView.setText(campaign.getTitle());
    TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.description);
    descriptionTextView.setText(campaign.getDescription());
    return v;

}
```

I get `Cannot resolve method loadInBackground(anonymous com.parse.getDataCallback, anonymous com.parse.ProgressCallback)`
So, does `loadInBackground()` not contain a ProgressCallback? If so, how can I make my progress bar set percentage depending on how much it loads?

Answer (score 0):

The `loadInBackground` function does not contain a progress callback. You should use [getDataInBackground](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseFile.html#getDataInBackground%28com.parse.GetDataCallback,%20com.parse.ProgressCallback%29) instead

Comment: Do I simply sub `loadInBackground` with `getDataInBackground`? Is it that simple?

Comment: Putting `mealImage.getDataInBackground` gives me a `cannot resolve method getDataInBackground` error.

Comment: should I put `photoFile.getDataInBackground` instead?

Comment: As far as I know, progress callback is only supported on the ParseFile not on a ParseImageView